# Login background changed, but lock screen persists

Tags: unity, login-screen, lock-screen, desktop-background

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I was able to change the login screen background with the Ubuntu Tweak tool, but for some reason, the lock screen does not change. I already checked in dconf-editor, the key that is pointed out as the source for the lock screen background is correct (com.canonical.unity-greeter-background).
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this up myself: the lock screen uses the desktop background.